# Scroll the content of the overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Goal:
Big content need to be scrolled.

Problem:
I don't know how to create it by having a scroll that you can scroll when the content is long.

Thank you!

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
    
     $('body').addClass('noscroll');   
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
    
     $('body').removeClass('noscroll');
    
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
   position: relative;
   top: 10%;
   width: 70%;
   text-align: left;
   margin: 30px auto;
   background: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}


.noscroll { 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">CANDY</a>    
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide downwards from the top:</p>
  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
   
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>  

<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your overlay content a height so it knows what the overflow is, also I would change it from scroll to auto so the scrollbar only shows up when it needs one:

```
.overlay-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Updated snippet:**

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
    
     $('body').addClass('noscroll');   
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
    
     $('body').removeClass('noscroll');
    
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
   position: relative;
   top: 10%;
   width: 70%;
   text-align: left;
   margin: 30px auto;
   background: white;
   overflow-y: auto;
   height: 100%;     
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}


.noscroll { 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">CANDY</a>    
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide downwards from the top:</p>
  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
   
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>  

<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The code of the website with overly scroll don't work

Comment: You're welcome - did this work? I wasn't sure as your comment says something doesn't

Comment: I tried the ".overlay-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
} " and it works. Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add `height`

```
.overlay-content {
    height: 85%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some height for this:

```
.overlay-content {
    height: 80vh;
}
```